# How to call div id(id="addObjectForm"), if i press the button(Add Row)?

Tags: javascript, html

If i press the "Add Row" button, i have to call the div id="**addObjectForm**" 
This is my sample code.

```
<div class="row mt" id="addObjectForm">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" id="addRowButton">Add Row</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a sample code

Comment: What do you mean with "call the div..."? What should happen?

Comment: <div class="row mt" id="addObjectForm">    
     <div class="col-sm-1">    
      <button type="button" id="addRowButton">Add Row</button>    
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: This is my sample code

Comment: You question does not make any sense. Think about what you are trying to ask, then edit your question

Comment: @BMAM Where is the sample code? All you posted is the markup but no code you are having issues with? Please post the code you currently use trying to get that div id. What research have you done, have to attempted search for how to get an element's identifier? Please do and try out some code and post it when you get any issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the jQuery in code below....

```js
$('#addRowButton').click(function(e){
  var id = $(this).closest('.mt').attr('id');
  alert('ID : '+id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row mt" id="addObjectForm">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" id="addRowButton">Add Row</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you  @Gyandeep Sharma

Comment: Your welcome.... Please mark answer accept... thanks